# What do I lose by entering the Holy Pillar?

Tags: bravely-default

Before entering the Holy Pillar, you are warned that you cannot return. So, naturally, I entered without thinking twice.

What exactly could I have missed? Are certain events/items lost permanently?

Comment: I don't have the full list but I do know that the next few chapters all have harder monsters so you miss out on a few Vampire Genomes until the last chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do everything after the Holy Pillar that you could do in Chapter 4. Some Genome abilities may be harder to get, though, but they are attainable in the Bonus Dungeon.

Comment: Does this include acquiring asterisks that you missed if you choose to skip over the optional boss fights in the first cycle (Ch. 0 - 4)?

Comment: According to [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/729328-bravely-default/68212989) - Yes, you can.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the info. +1 for source provided.